# A build system on a selected text

Tags: python, postgresql, sublimetext3, sublimetext, psql

I have the build system for Postgres:

```
{
    "cmd": ["psql", "-U", "postgres", "-d", "test", "-o", "c:/app/sql/result.txt", "-f", "$file"]
}
```

It works fine, executes current file and sends results to the file `c:/app/sql/result.txt`.

I want to modify it to automatically save current selection to a file and run `psql` on that file. Can it be done in a build system?

Comment: No, it cannot. You'll have to either do that manually, or write a Sublime plugin to do that, then call the build system. You may find the [API reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) useful.

Comment: @MattDMo - thank you, I'm going to get familiar with ST plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my learning has borne fruit let me answer my own question. The simple plugin saves a selected text in a file and calls a build system:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ExecuteSelectedSqlCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():  
            if not region.empty():  
                with open('/a/temporary/file', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(self.view.substr(region))
                self.view.window().run_command('build')
                break
```